# inserting data into a database using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have been developing an appointment system over the past few weeks using php, mysql and javascript. I've come across a problem when trying to insert data into a table. I am using javascript on a php page to send a GET request to a php file which generates a table from database records. I have added a 'Book Appointment' button at the end of each row which should let the user confirm their appointment if its available and book it. Ive wrote all the code to get all relevant data from the table and then insert into a new table. The problem is that it does not insert. If I did this in php i could do this the way how im doing it now, but it would not be dynamic. I do not get any errors, it just does not insert the data. Do I need to do a ajax request in the javascript? I know theres lots of available help online with these sorts of problems, but cant seem to find an answer for my particular problem.

Heres my code:

```
<body>

<div id="textDisplay"<h1>Doctor availability and appointments will be  listed here...</h1></div>

</body>
<script>
function showAppointments(str, patient_id, patient_surname) {
if (str == "" || patient_id == "") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
 } else { 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML =   xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getAppointments.php?listOption="+str +  "&patient_id="+patient_id + "&surname="+patient_surname, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
}
```

This javascript function sends a get request to a php page with some data appended in the url so it can be picked up by the php page.

getAppointments.php then generates the table with relevant database records.

***** getAppointments.php: *****

```
 include 'dbConnect.php';
$listOptionVal = intval($_GET['listOption']);
$patient_id = $_GET['patient_id'];
$surname = $_GET['surname'];


 if ($listOptionVal == 0) {

$sql="SELECT * FROM patient_info, appointment_slots INNER JOIN doctors ON appointment_slots.doctor_id=doctors.doctor_id WHERE
 appointment_time BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '12:00:00' AND appointment_date = '2015-11-02' AND patient_id = $patient_id;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<center><h2>Available Appointments</h2><center>";
echo "<center><table>
    <tr>
    <th>Patient ID</th>
    <th>Patient Surname</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Times</th>
    <th>Avaialable</th>
    <th>Doctor</th>
    <th>Book Appointment</th>
    </tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="' .       $row['patient_id'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="' . $row['surname'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_date" value="' .     $row['appointment_date'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_time" value="' . $row['appointment_time'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_avaliability" value="' . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . '" />';

echo "<form action='confirmed-appointments.php' method='post'    enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['patient_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . "</td>";

 if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'Y') {
    echo "<td style='color: #ACFB62;'>".$row['doctor_forename']."     </td>";
 } else if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'N') {
    echo "<td style='color:  #FF6666;'>".$row['doctor_forename']."   </td>";
}
  echo "<td>
        <input type='submit' name='bookAppointment' value='Book  Appointment'>
    </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 } 
 }
echo "</table></center>";
echo "</form>";
```

This will then generate a table with appointment availability times. There is a button appended to each row allowing the user to book that appointment. This is where I want to send the data to the database and then loop through the results and show on a new page.

**** confirmed appointments.php - should be looping through rows of inserted data ****

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['bookAppointment'])) {
var_dump($_POST);
$patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$forename = $_POST['appointment_date'];
$dob = $_POST['appointment_time'];
$doctor = $_POST['doctor_forename'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO confirmed_appointments SET patient_id='" .   $patient_id . "', surname='" . $surname .  "', appointment_date='" . $appointment_date . "', appointment_time='" . $appointment_time . "', doctor='" . $doctor . "'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record added successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "
        " . $conn->error;
}
}

$sql = "SELECT * from confirmed_appointments;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<table border = 1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['patient_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['doctor'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The data does not get inserted so therefore does not get displayed on the confirmed-appointments.php page. I hope i've been clear enough and I hope my question does not get closed!! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

assuming all the post data is correct , db connection success and there's no typo from any of your variable.. sometimes just doesn't works without closing double quote...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO confirmed_appointments SET patient_id='" . $patient_id . "', surname='" . $surname .  "', appointment_date='" . $appointment_date . "', appointment_time='" . $appointment_time . "', doctor='" . $doctor . "'";
```

instead, did you try to var_dump your $_POST? i dont think you have any value post from your form.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<form method='get'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['patient_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . "</td>";

if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'Y') {
    echo "<td style='color: #ACFB62;'>".$row['doctor_forename']."     </td>";
} else if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'N') {
    echo "<td style='color:  #FF6666;'>".$row['doctor_forename']." </td>";
}
echo "<td>
        <input type='submit' name='bookAppointment' value='Book  Appointment' action='confirmed-appointments.php'>
    </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
 } 
}
```

you're just displaying the value and the form method is get, do you have any input value?

i saw your variable at

```
$patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$forename = $_POST['appointment_date'];
$dob = $_POST['appointment_time'];
$doctor = $_POST['doctor_forename'];
```

but where is your

```
input type="text" name="patient_id" value=" . $row['patient_id']
```

at your getAppointments.php?

---

getAppointments.php

```
include 'dbConnect.php';
$listOptionVal = intval($_GET['listOption']);
$patient_id = $_GET['patient_id'];
$surname = $_GET['surname'];


 if ($listOptionVal == 0) {

 $sql="SELECT * FROM patient_info, appointment_slots INNER JOIN doctors ON appointment_slots.doctor_id=doctors.doctor_id WHERE
 appointment_time BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '12:00:00' AND     appointment_date = '2015-11-02' AND patient_id = $patient_id;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<center><h2>Available Appointments</h2><center>";
echo "<form method='post' action = 'confirmed-appointments.php'>";
echo "<center><table>
<tr>
<th>Patient ID</th>
<th>Patient Surname</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Times</th>
<th>Avaialable</th>
<th>Doctor</th>
<th>Book Appointment</th>
</tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

// things that you might miss out 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="' . $row['patient_id'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="' . $row['surname'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_date" value="' . $row['appointment_date'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_time" value="' . $row['appointment_time'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_avaliability" value="' . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="doctor_forename" value="' . $row['doctor_forename'] . '" />';


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['patient_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_time'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . "</td>";

    if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'Y') {
        echo "<td style='color: #ACFB62;'>".$row['doctor_forename']."     </td>";
    } else if ($row['appointment_avaliability'] == 'N') {
        echo "<td style='color:  #FF6666;'>".$row['doctor_forename']." </td>";
    }
    echo "<td>
            <input type='submit' name='bookAppointment' value='1'>
        </td>";
echo "</tr>";
 } 
}
 echo "</table></center>";
echo "</form>";
```

---

confirm appointments.php

```
if (isset($_POST['bookAppointment'])) {
    $patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $forename = $_POST['appointment_date'];
    $dob = $_POST['appointment_time'];
    $doctor = $_POST['doctor_forename'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO confirmed_appointments SET patient_id='" . $patient_id . "', surname='" . $surname .  "', appointment_date='" . $appointment_date . "', appointment_time='" . $appointment_time . "', doctor='" . $doctor . "'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record added successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "
            " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: go var_dump($_POST); at your  confirmed appointments.php just after if (isset($_GET['bookAppointment'])) {
and you see if there's any value of post?

Comment: yes getAppointment.php are displaying the data but did you set the data into input field so the form able to post value to confirmed appointments.php? just try to print_r($_POST); at confirmed appointments.php to see what's the data that being post from getAppointment.php

Comment: sorry if I cant understand your point. Im new to this. A code example would help if possible.

Comment: ive updated my code. It uses _POST now but still no difference

Comment: check the answer that just editted for your getAppointment.php and confirm appointments.php and what's the output there. after you got your post data, remove the (echo '<pre>' till exit;)

Comment: what's the data that post out? no data posted at all?
replace your form open tag
echo '<form action="confirmed-appointments.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

Comment: i dont think any data gets posted

Comment: // things that you might miss out 

echo '<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="' . $row['patient_id'] . '" />';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="' . $row['surname'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_date" value="' . $row['appointment_date'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_time" value="' . $row['appointment_time'] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="appointment_avaliability" value="' . $row['appointment_avaliability'] . '" />';

with this also it's not working?

Comment: i've tested here and everything goes well... did you try var_dump($_POST); at your confirm-appointments.php and see what's the variable?

Comment: Yes no variable comes through. Also when i click the button i dont get re-directed to the confirmed-appointments.php page

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas :/

Comment: Do check where you put the form tag and where did i.. In your case..  Each data will create one new form.. But it should be just one form which contain all data.. And ur input value miss out one doctor forehead

Comment: Thanks for you help. Ive managed to fix it so it inserts data in to the database. The only problem now is that every time i refresh the confirmed-appointments.php page it adds a new record. It also adds the same time and doctorname to each record. Any ideas? Im so grateful for your help

Comment: Also, when I remove rows from the database, i refresh the page and they are still there even though there deleted from the database

Comment: Its weird.... As soon as a I delete the rows from the database and then refresh, they all get added in again :\

Comment: are you sure that the rows of data you viewing from your table is the one that you deleted or the one that just re-insert by your script again? var dump again when refresh and see if the $_POST is still exist. if it's exist which means that the query will get run again. suggestion to you is separate your server and client side code into different files but not all mix into one.